# How to display ok button at bottom in .net compact framework?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, messagebox

I am developing mobile application in C#. I am using the following code in my application to display the messagebox but the button ok is displayed at the top right corner. I want to display the ok button at the bottom. This is my code

```
MessageBox.Show("Records successfully inserted","Customer Entry",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.None,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```

Is anything wrong in my code? or should I need to do different things ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the standard MessageBox behaviour in the compact framework to display the OK button at the top right corner (unless, I think, you are on a Windows Mobile 6.5.x, in that case it would be displayed at the bottom).

The only way I can see of "moving" that OK button at the bottom would be to create a form and use it instead of the MessageBox. That means creating a kind of custom MessageBox class.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite annoying i agree. Especially when working on small touchscreens where pressing the OK in the top right is difficult.

Since you just want to present the OK button id suggest using `MessageBox.OKCancel` instead and just treat any button press as OK. Setting anything other than OK will show the buttons at the bottom.

```
MessageBox.Show("Records successfully inserted","Customer Entry",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.None,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```